# Windows 3.1 Installation

Tags: unattended, windows-3.1

I'm not very familiar with Microsoft's OSs pre-Windows 9x.

Is it possible to do a Windows 3.1 unattended installation in a real (not virtual) machine using winnt?

EDIT: According to one of the comments, winnt is only available to do unattended upgrade. Isn't there any way to do this? How was this done back in the day?

Comment: To install 3.1, you need a Win 3.1 installation disk.  Where on earth would you find one?  Winnt does an installation or upgrade to XP and for that, you need the XP files (and where on earth would you find that?).

Comment: @fixer1234: On the web, of course. Both are _very_ common.

Comment: @fixer1234 Ha, I have the floppies :) And I think it's available on TechNet.

Comment: @grawity - I would love a link to XP.  I haven't been able to find it for years.

Comment: If what you want is a 3.1 installation, Winnt won't help.  That's for upgrading 3.1 to XP.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yeah, I see that now. Can't really find anything about 3.1 unattended installation or deployment for that matter.

Comment: 3.1 probably fits on one floppy.  How long could installation take?

Comment: re: XP -- it looks like Technet might have XP Pro.  I was looking for Home Edition or Media Center Edition.

Comment: @fixer1234 6 floppies actually. Around 8Mb. That thing was huge. It's a real machine (old). It takes a lot of time :)

Comment: If it is on 6 floppies, how do you remove and insert sequential floppies unattended?

Comment: @fixer1234 Damn, that's a good question. I _think_ Windows 3.1 was released on CD-ROM as well, so that would be a solution. But, in any case, I would think that unattended installation of that OS was already needed in the early 90s. I mean, Windows 3.11 was officially called _Windows for Workgroups 3.11_...

Comment: I remember "automating" Windows 3.1 installations using zip files and then Backit. All of its settings were just .INI files, so I could do a clean install and zip it up. Unzip to the correct location and it was done. Edit a couple INI files to change a couple settings here and there, etc.